Options to achieve parallel execution in C#
I have a use case where I need to process n number of operations, which involves other I/O operations.
Method 1: Uses ConcurrentBag<T>.
But worried that the I/O operations  in the ProcessSomething method would add further complications with the Task.Run addition of async.
var fullList = new ConcurrentBag<ViewModel>();

var tasks = new List<Task>();
IncomingList.ForEach(w => tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
{
    ViewModel somethingCompletewithMetaData= await ProcessSomething(something, token);
    if (somethingCompletewithMetaData!= null)
    {
        fullList.Add(somethingCompletewithMetaData);
    }
})));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

Method 2:
Using projection and not using ConcurrentBag<T>. Looks cleaner and simpler.
var tasks1 = IncomingList.Select(x => ProcessSomething(x, token))
                .ToList();
ViewModel[] result1 = await Task.WhenAll(tasks1);
IEnumerable<ViewModel> fullWikis = result1.Where(x => x is not null);

Method 3:
Using Parallel.ForEachAsync
ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5
};

var fullContents = new ConcurrentBag<SomethingViewModel>();

await Parallel.ForEachAsync(contents, parallelOptions, async (content, token) =>
{
    SomethingViewModel wikiComplete = await ProcessSomething(content, token);
    if (contentComplete != null)
    {
        fullContents.Add(contentComplete);
    }
});

For clarification, ProcessSomething is a long running task which makes external API calls and processes some data and returns a view model, which gets added to a list.
public Task<ContentViewModel> ProcessSomething(content, token)
{
    bool hasPermission = await _externalService.HasPermission(content.userId);
    if (hasPermission)
    {
        var content = await _anotherService.Get(content.id);
        var author = await _anotherService2.Get(content.userId);
        return new ContentViewModel(content, author)
    }
    return null;
}

My question is, which method should I be using?
Method 3 was what I would ideally have used, but it took double the processing time when running in azure. Method 1 and 2 were comparable. Measured them using Stopwatch.
The app runs in Azure as a HTTP triggered function app.

I would measure both cases, It's pretty hard to make a guess which one performs better.

In either case: take a look at what happens if exceptions are thrown in ProcessSomething. Then reconsider.

The "Best way" is not a QA question suited for Stack Overflow. It tends to attract opinionated answers, especially since you don't describe the requirements. Please read [ask] in the [help].

I would be careful when trying to parallelize IO. Disks tend to perform best with large, sequential operations, and network requests often have some form of rate-limit or other bottleneck. I would start by doing some profiling and try to figure out where the bottleneck actually is before considering what approach to use.

Both options are bad. They fire off too many tasks, more than there are cores to handle. Good options depend on what ProcessSomething is actually doing. One option would be to use a ConcurrentQueue to collect results and use await Parallel.ForEachAsyc(IncomingList,async (x,t)=>{ var result=await Process(x,t); queue.Enqueue(res);});. The degree of parallelism can be configured through options

Another good option would be to use a TransformBlock, eg TransformBlock<X,ViewModel>(x=>ProcessSomething(x,token)) with a DOP higher than 1 and feed non-null results to a BufferBlock. Multiple blocks can be linked together in a pipeline to perform different jobs one after the other

The only significant difference between the methods 1 and 2 is that the first offloads the invocation of the ProcessSomething to the ThreadPool, and the second does not. That's because the first uses the Task.Run and the second does not. Whether you will use LINQ to create the tasks, and whether you will use a concurrent collection to gather the results, it's solely stylistic and it doesn't affect the performance characteristics of the operation. You could use the Task.Run with LINQ as well:
Task<ViewModel>[] tasks = IncomingList
    .Select(x => Task.Run(() => ProcessSomething(x, token)))
    .ToArray();
ViewModel[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

Adding the Task.Run has an observable effect only if the ProcessSomething does not return a Task immediately. In other words if it performs synchronous work (either CPU-bound work or blocking I/O work) before returning the Task. Judging from what you are showing in the question, the ProcessSomething most likely returns a Task<ContentViewModel> instantaneously, so the addition of Task.Run shouldn't make any difference. The Task.Run essentially parallelizes the creation of the tasks. If the creation of a task is instantaneous, parallelizing it won't improve the overall performance. You can't optimize for speed an operation that takes zero time to complete.
The 3rd approach (Parallel.ForEachAsync) is the recommended way to parallelize asynchronous work in general (with the ASP.NET being a possible exception). It is preferable to the Task.WhenAll for (mainly) two reasons: allows to control the maximum degree of parallelism, and stops ASAP the execution in case of an error. Controlling the maximum degree of parallelism is a good thing because you don't want to bombard the remote server with hundreds or thousands web requests. If you do, the performance of the remote server might degrade, or it might consider you to be a DOS attacker and block your IP. Being conscious about the stress that you put on remote machines is part of what makes you a responsible professional.
If you know for sure that the remote server (or whatever hardware supports the API that you are calling) can handle infinite parallelism, you can just configure the Parallel.ForEachAsync accordingly:
ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Int32.MaxValue
};

The ParallelOptions has also a CancellationToken property that you might want to configure as well.

The first two options are not good, because they start a very large number of tasks at once, whether the remote services can handle this or not. Even if one of these is a local database, this code can end up flooding or blocking it.
Option #3 is good, although ConcurrentBag isn't the best container option. That type is meant for fast thread-local storage with slower access across threads.
A better option is #4 - use Dataflow blocks to create a pipeline of steps that call the three services concurrently, using a Degree of parallelism appropriate to each. That's similar to a Powershell or Bash pipeline where each program processes a stream of input/objects independently of the others.
This allows optimizing every step and handling variations in service responses through buffering and backpressure.
record WikiPage(Content Content,Author Author);

record Result<T>(T? Message,bool OK);

var permissionStep=new TransformBlock<Request,Result<Request>>(CheckPermissions,
    new (){ 
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism=5,
        BoundedCapacity=5
    });
var service1Step=new TransformBlock<Result<Request>,Result<Content>>(GetContent,
    new (){ 
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism=10, //Slower service, make more calls
        BoundedCapacity=5
    });
var service2Step=new TransformBlock<Result<Content>,Result<WikiPage>>(GetAuthor,
    new (){ 
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism=5,
        BoundedCapacity=5
    });
var buffer=new BufferBlock<Result<WikiPage>>();

var deniedStep=new ActionBlock<Result<Request>>(req=>_logger.LogWarning("Request Denied for {req.Request.ID}");


Once we have the blocks we link them in a pipeline, with denied requests routed to the logging block
var linkOptions=new DataflowLinkOptions {
    PropageateCompletion=true
};

permissionStep.LinkTo(service1Step, linkOptions, p=>p.OK);
permissionStep.LinkTo(deniedStep, linkOptions, p=>!p.OK);
service1Step.LinkTo(service2Step,linkOptions);
service2Step.LinkTo(buffer,linkOptions);

Then we can start pumping requests. If the input buffers of any block become full, the SendAsync of the head block with await. This way we don't end up with hundreds of messages in flight or in a buffer if one service is too slow.
foreach(var req in someRequests)
{
    await permissionStep.SendAsync(req);
}
buffer.Complete();

await buffer.Completion;

Finally, we can retrieve the results from the tail block. If this was a SignalR or gRPC service though, we could send each WikiPage to the client as it became available.
if(buffer.TryReceiveAll(out var wikiPages))
{
    var pages=wikiPages.Where(p=>p.Message!=null)
                       .Select(=>p.Message)
                       .ToList();
    return View(wikiPages);
}
else
{
    return View(Array.Empty<WikiPage>());
}

Each of the actual worker is executed by a separate task and can be asynchronous. Using Result<T> allows easier error handling, eg :
async Result<Request> CheckPermissions(Request req)
{
    try
    {
        bool hasPermission = await _externalService.HasPermission(content.userId);
        return new Result<Request>(req,hasPermission);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Do something then
        return new Result<Request(null,false);
    }
}

Subsequent methods can discard failing messages, or LinkTo can be used to redirect failures to other logging steps
async Result<Content> GetContent(Result<Request> req)
{
    if(!req.OK)
    {
        return new Result<Content>(null,false);
    }
    try
    {
        var content = await _anotherService.Get(req.id);
        retun new Result<Content>(content,true);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Do something then
        return new Result<Content>(null,false);
    }
}

The result class can be more complex. Some variations use Result<T>(T? Message, Exception? Error), others use an IResult<T> interface with Good and Error child types.

I wouldn't recommend to anyone to use the TPL Dataflow today. At least not for creating simple straightforward pipelines. This library lacks the robustness that is required for being considered a professional tool. In your example if the GetAuthor fails, the pipeline will complete with failure while the CheckPermissions and GetContent are still running. A.k.a. fire-and-forget. Terrible. Even worse, if the GetAuthor fails, the feeding code await permissionStep.SendAsync(req); will deadlock, because all blocks are capacity-bounded. Send this library to the museum, where it belongs.

"A better option is #4" -- Presumably it is better than the 3rd option because it allows to configure the degree of parallelism independently for each individual heterogeneous asynchronous operation. That's correct, and would make #4 the better option if there were no drawbacks. Unfortunately there are, they are plenty, and they are not trivially solvable. So you might want to reconsider the "better" in your answer. It is a dubious alternative option at most.
